# Samsung Note 4 - Network Locked - But which carrier?

Tags: locked-out, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I bought one Galaxy Note 4 on Amazon. I used it in Europe with no problems. Few months are passed and now I moved to China for a while. Well, I can't use my phone here because it is Network Locked (asks for a code at the splash screen). Nothing when I bought it let me suppose this phone was locked to some network, nor I can find any information inside the phone (or the box, or some appearing logo) suggesting to which network it is locked.

[image: Phone Screen]

I am aware there are many service to unlock a phone, but I can't even step up the process of unlocking since I have no idea which network my phone is locked to.

My questions:

1) how to know which network carrier I'm locked on?
I got some information on the *#0011# menu, but nothing useful, also in about of the phone no hints.

2) Are this unlock services reliable?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this page: [IMEI INFO](http://www.imei.info/)

It may tell you the carrier who locked your phone. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @webo80 the link is interesting indeed, but no information about the carrier. Am I looking the wrong way?

Comment: It looks that it will show you the operator only in some devices. Sorry! Looks that you can switch on the phone, is there some boot image or so, but if you bought this phone in Amazon in the EU, it must be carrier free! I would try contacting Amazon.

Comment: Amazon can't help because the seller disconnected from their platform :! Weird, above all I can't find a way to unlock one phone.

Comment: Try to unlock it with a SIM-based solution, not with the IMEI. Look for "gevey" or similar

Comment: Also an interesting solution, but with the price for a gevey sim I could buy an unlock code directly.

Comment: But you must know the locker operator for buy an unlock code

Comment: You're right. Some of them don't need an operator it seems. But they also state service is not 100% reliable. I'll study more about a gevey sim.